# Error adding a movieclip that adds more movieclips to self in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class documentclass extends MovieClip
    {
        public var playscreen:avoiderclass;

        public function documentclass() 
        {
            playscreen.addEventListener(playerEvent.DEAD, onplayerdeath);
            playscreen.x = 0;
            playscreen.y = 0;
            playscreen = new avoiderclass();
            addChild(playscreen);
        }
        public function onplayerdeath(PlayerEvent:playerEvent):void
        {
            var Gameover:gameover = new gameover();
            Gameover.x = 0;
            Gameover.y = 0;
            addChild(Gameover);

            playscreen = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Ok, It worked when the stage (this class) was the class that pulled the player and enemy movieclips into it. Then i added this for the stage and made the other one for playscreen...
I have no idea why it isn't working, but could anyone give me any possibilities for why it wouldn't, no errors pop up...

Comment: what's wrong? YOu've not really explained what is wrong. Without a description of what's not working and the avoiderclass code, we can't really help you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set variable playscreen to a new avoiderclass object like this:

```
        playscreen = new avoiderclass();
```

before doing..

```
        playscreen.addEventListener(playerEvent.DEAD, onplayerdeath);
        playscreen.x = 0;
        playscreen.y = 0;
```

Please try this way.

```
public class documentclass extends MovieClip {
    public var playscreen:avoiderclass;

    public function documentclass(){
        // construct the object first
        playscreen = new avoiderclass();
        // then manipulate it.
        playscreen.addEventListener(playerEvent.DEAD, onplayerdeath);
        playscreen.x = 0;
        playscreen.y = 0;
        addChild(playscreen);
    }
```

And here in that function do not forget to remove playscreen from displaylist

```
    public function onplayerdeath(PlayerEvent:playerEvent):void {
        var Gameover:gameover = new gameover();
        Gameover.x = 0;
        Gameover.y = 0;
        addChild(Gameover);
        // first remove the playscreen from display list
        removeChild(playscreen);
        // then set it to null, now really unreachable and eligible for gc
        playscreen = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to understand your post, but once I realized you were basically saying "don't set x's and y's before you put the playscreen = new avoiderclass(); line... Thanks

Comment: Ok, tried to use a more understandable language. And you are wellcome.